# Multi-Threading with files

Tags: c, multithreading, file

So let's say I have the following code where I open a file, read the contents line by line and then use each line for a function somewhere else and then when I'm done rewind the file.

```
FILE *file = Open_File();
char line[max];
while (!EndofFile()) 
{
    int length = GetLength(line);
    if (length > 0) 
    {
       DoStuffToLine(line)
    }
}
rewind(file);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to use threads here to add concurrency. Since I'm just reading the file and not writing to it I feel like I don't have to worry about race conditioning. However I'm not sure how to handle the code that's in the while loop because if one thread is looping over the file and another thread is looping over the file at the same time, would they cause each other to skip over lines, make other errors, etc? What's a good way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this to improve read performance, you're going to likely be disappointed since this will almost surely be disk I/O bound.  Adding more threads won't help the OS and disk controller fetch data any faster.

However, if you're trying to just process the data in parallel, that's another matter.  In that case, I would read the entire file into a memory buffer somewhere, then have your threads process it in parallel.  That way you don't have to worry about thread safety with rewinding the file pointer or any other annoying issues like it.

You'll likely still need to use other locking mechanisms for the multithreaded parts of course, depending on exactly what you're doing, but you shouldn't have to worry about what the standard library is going to do when you start accessing a file with multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for the help! In my file, each line is a key to a hashmap, so when I call "DoStuffToLine", I'm using the key to look up a value. So would that also benefit from threading? Or is reading from a hashmap bound by the same I/O you mentioned?

Comment: @user1782677 Ok, first off, read the entire file into memory first instead of trying to retrieve pieces of it. Do this before worrying about other types of optimization.

Comment: @user1782677 Reading the hashmap would be memory I/O bound, so no, it shouldn't be as big a problem as reading from the disk.  However, this may still not offer much performance benefit depending on a hundred other details.  Unless your hashmap is very large this may not help much.

Answer (score 1):

The concurrency adds some race condition problems:

**1.** The EndofFile() function is evaluated at the start of the loop, it may always happens that this function returns true for two threads, then one thread reaches the end of file and the other thread attempts to read the file.You never know when a thread may be in execution;
 **2.** Same is valid for the GetLength function: when a thread has the length information, the length may change because another thread may read another line;
 **3.** You are reading a file sequentially, even if you rewind it, it may always occur that the current position of the IO pointer is altered by some other thread.

Furthermore, as Telgin pointed out, reading a file is not CPU bound, but I/O bound, so is the system to read the file.You can't improve the performance because you need some locks, and locking to guarantee thread safety just introduces overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best approach. However, you could read the file. Then store it in two separate objects and read the objects instead of the file. Just make sure to do cleanup afterward.